# Android listview lagging with complex layout

Tags: android, performance, listview

Like the title say, i create list view which each item display image, three line text, and a button, but the view is so lagging even in samsung galaxy mega dual core, here my item view xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5.0dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/compositeListViewItemThumbnailImage"
        android:layout_width="60.0dip"
        android:layout_height="60.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/_empty_strings" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/compositeListViewItemFirstLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/compositeListViewItemThumbnailImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/compositeListViewItemThumbnailImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/compositeListViewItemThumbnailImage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="16.0sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/compositeListViewItemFirstLineText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:lines="1"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
        <TextView
            android:textSize="12.0sp"
            android:id="@+id/compositeListViewItemSecondLineText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:lines="1"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
        <TextView
            android:textSize="14.0sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/compositeListViewItemThirdLineText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/compositeListViewItemActionButton"
        android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="5.0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dip"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

as it might / might not be affected by the adapter view, i also put it here

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<?> items;
    private int itemLayout;
    private String[] itemFieldsName;
    private int[] itemElements;
    private Context ctx;

    public SimpleAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<?> items, int itemLayout, int[] itemElements, String[] itemFieldsName) {
        super(ctx, itemLayout, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.itemElements = itemElements;
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
        this.itemFieldsName = itemFieldsName;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(this.itemLayout, null);
        }
        Object item = this.items.get(position);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.itemElements.length; i++) {
            Object value = getValue(item, Character.toUpperCase(this.itemFieldsName[i].charAt(0)) + this.itemFieldsName[i].substring(1));
            View elementView = null;
            if (itemView != null) {
                elementView = itemView.findViewById(this.itemElements[i]);
                if ((elementView instanceof TextView)) {
                    ((TextView) elementView).setText(value.toString());
                } else if ((elementView instanceof SmartImageView)) {
                    ((SmartImageView) elementView).setImageUrl(value.toString());
                } else if ((elementView instanceof Button)) {
                    ((Button) elementView).setText(value.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        return itemView;
    }

    private Object getValue(Object obj, String fieldName) {
        ArrayList<String> fieldsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        int length;
        String str = Character.toUpperCase(fieldName.charAt(0)) + fieldName.substring(1);
        Object value = new Object();
        try {
            value = obj.getClass().getMethod("get" + str, new Class[0]).invoke(obj);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            value = fieldName;
        }
        return value;
    }

    private String trimString(String string, int length, boolean soft) {
        if(string == null || string.trim().isEmpty()){
            return string;
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(string);
        int actualLength = length - 3;
        if(sb.length() > actualLength){
            if(!soft)
                return sb.insert(actualLength, "...").substring(0, actualLength+3);
            else {
                int endIndex = sb.indexOf(" ",actualLength);
                return sb.insert(endIndex,"...").substring(0, endIndex+3);
            }
        }
        return string;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me where i was wrong?,

tell me if you need more explanation / code resource

Comment: what is actual problem ?

Comment: Checkout [holder pateren](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Comment: @Kumar i edited my question, sorry for being not clear, plese re-read them

Comment: It seams that you're `getView()` is doing a lot of extra actions (calculations). As #blazsolar said try using the ViewHolder pattern. And try to refactor you're code, to avoid using `instanceof` checks and getting methods via reflection. This only increases the time of every `getView()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding an inner view inside an inflated layout is among the most common operations in Android. This is usually done through a View method called **findViewById()**. This method will recursively go through the view tree looking for a child with a given IDcode. Using **findViewById()** on static UI layouts is totally fine but, as you’ve seen, ListView calls the adapter’s **getView()** very frequently when scrolling. **findViewById()** might perceivably hit scrolling performance in ListViews—especially if your row layout is non-trivial.

The **View Holder pattern** is about reducing the number of **findViewById()** calls in the adapter’s **getView()**. In practice, the View Holder is a lightweight inner class that holds direct references to all inner views from a row. You store it as a tag in the row’s view after inflating it. This way you’ll only have to use **findViewById()** when you first create the layout. Here’s the code sample with View Holder pattern applied:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = convertView.getTag();
}

holder.text.setText("Position " + position);

return convertView;
```

}

```
private static class ViewHolder {
public TextView text;
```

}

Comment: Beside using viewholder, string length displayed in listview likely affect this problem too. Before, i put a very long string directly acquired from network, now after i trim the string the view is much lighter. Thanks, i mark your answer as correct

Comment: View Holder makes ListView scrooling fast and easier. best way into android

Answer (score 0):

There is one known issue with android:singleLine where it kills performance on ListViews drastically. Please see this question [Why does android:singleLine="true" make ListView scrolling very laggy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124985/why-does-androidsingleline-true-make-listview-scrolling-very-laggy)

Remove it from your layout and use maxLines instead.